# How to connect Rest webservices server with MFP server?

Tags: java, rest, ionic-framework, ibm-mobilefirst

We develop mobile applications using **ionic framework** in the client side and **rest webservices** in  server side. From client side, I 'm able to connect with mfp server successfully.
Now I'm  trying to connect my web services server with mfp server for sending pushnotifications . But I am getting 405 error.This is the code I have written

```
URLConnection connection = new    URL("http://localhost:9441/mfp/api/az/v1/token").openConnection();
connection.setDoOutput(true); // Triggers POST.
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
connection.setRequestProperty("grant_type", "client_credentials");
connection.setRequestProperty("scope", "messages.write");
connection.setRequestProperty("scope", "push.application.com.ionicframework.example854621");    
InputStream response = connection.getInputStream();
System.out.println("response"+response);
```

This is the response I'm getting

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 405 for URL: http://180.151.63.116:9441/mfp/api/az/v1/token
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1441)
at com.sai.laps.webservice.server.authentication.mfp.main(mfp.java:24)
```

Where am I going wrong? How can I connect my rest web service server with MFP server?

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, **first** I 'ld suggest ***not to use*** **`connection.getOutputStream()`**. This will create issue.

**Next,** Please **test the connection** if it is connecting or not.

You have to add `Authorization` parameter in `setRequestProperty`

Yes, I remember, I too have faced the same issue due to some certificate error and I had to import the certificate in Java level and after that it worked. (Although I faced some other challenge (Multiple connection) issue afterwards, but that too worked...see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33910154/java-net-httpurlconnection-check-test-connection-while-only-post-method-is-ava#Kindly%20Suggest%20me%20how%20can%20I%20check%20the%20connection%20is%20established%20or%20not))

Anyways, you try the below code and if it is yet not connecting, please share the exception message

```
String wsURL = "https://hostservername:postnumber";
                String wsUserName = "someUserName";
                String wsPassword = "somePassword";

                try{
                    String authString = wsUserName+":"+wsPassword;
                    byte[] byteAuthStr = authString.getBytes();
                    String authBase64Str = Base64.encode(byteAuthStr);
                    System.out.println(authBase64Str);
                URL url = new URL(wsURL);
                URLConnection  conn =  url.openConnection();
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)conn;
                connection.setDoOutput(true); 
                /*connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                 connection.setRequestMethod("POST");*/   

connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic "+authBase64Str);
                connection.connect();
               System.out.println( connection.getResponseCode());
             boolean connected = false;
           switch (connection.getResponseCode()) {
           case HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK:
               System.out.println(url + " **OK**");
               connected = true;
               break; // fine, go on
           case HttpURLConnection.HTTP_GATEWAY_TIMEOUT:
               System.out.println(url + " **gateway timeout**");
               break;// retry
           case HttpURLConnection.HTTP_UNAVAILABLE:
               System.out.println(url + "**unavailable**");
               break;// retry, server is unstable
           default:
               System.out.println(url + " **unknown response code**.");
               break ; // abort
      }
    }catch(Exception ex){
                System.err.println("Error creating HTTP connection");
                System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you so much Surajit.. Now I can connect with the server. :)

Comment: Can you please click the 'Arrow' next to my answer to accept the answer ?

Comment: Have you used this connection to send push notifications to mobile?

Comment: Actually, I have never tried that thing....But I think, it is possible.

Comment: I can connect with MFP server using the URL given by you.
But my requirement is to use this URL to get access token from the server :http://localhost:9080/mfp/api/az/v1/token

On using this URL, I am getting the below error           

java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 405 for URL: http://localhost:9080/mfp/api/az/v1/token

Comment: Tell me one thing : Your webservice method is GET or POST ?

Comment: @Athistalakshmiselvaraj,
are you using `connection.getOutputStream()` in the above method ?

Comment: Yes...We use connection.getOutputStream() in the above method.     I am getting 400 as the response  code.

Comment: This is what , causing the error @Athistalakshmiselvaraj. Don't use this 
`connection.getOutputStream()`. Just follow the above practice as I have suggested ... use `connection.connect();` to connect. Try to get the response code.

Comment: I am getting same response code  when I use connection.connect() also.  I am using this URL: http://localhost:9080/mfp/api/az/v1/token     for getting access token.

Comment: Error creating HTTP connection
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: http://localhost:9080/mfp/api/az/v1/token
 at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1441)
 at java.net.URLConnection.getContent(URLConnection.java:688)
 at com.sai.laps.webservice.server.authentication.mfp.main(mfp.java:46)